# invalid records using inner join from two tables

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have this sql statement generated from codeigniter

```
SELECT * FROM (`products`) LEFT JOIN `products_attributes` ON `products_attributes`.`product_id` = `products`.`id` WHERE `products`.`category` = '1' AND `products`.`sub_category` = '1' AND `products_attributes`.`attribute_id` = '3' AND `products_attributes`.`attribute_id` = '4' AND `products_attributes`.`attribute_id` = '5' GROUP BY `products`.`id`
```

and I have these tables

products :
[image]
products_attributes :

[image]

I need to get the products with the all attributes only, so I will get the product id = 1 if the attributes are 3,4,5 and if the attributes are 3,4,5,6 I will not get product id = 1

Comment: Try to use `products_attributes.attribute_id IN (3,4,5)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sql query is totally wrong. What you did is:
Give me the record the attribute_id = 3 AND attribute_id = 4 AND attribute_id =  5 AND attribute_id = 6. One row can not be equal to 3 and 4 at the same time. 
What you need can be achieved in many different ways. For example:

```
SELECT
    products.id
FROM  products

    JOIN products_attributes ON products_attributes.product_id = products.id
WHERE
    products.category = '1'
    AND `products_attributes`.`attribute_id` IN (3,4,5,6)


GROUP BY
    products.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT `products_attributes`.`attribute_id`) = 4
```

If you specify just IN ... then it will take all the records who has at least 1 such attribute_id

Comment: You could probably remove the second `WHERE` condition and replace the `4` with a sub-query to get the total number of distinct attributes.

Comment: If I understood you right then the distinct values can be different but total can be the same in that case.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM (`products`) 
LEFT JOIN `products_attributes` 
ON `products_attributes`.`product_id` = `products`.`id` 
WHERE `products`.`category` = 1 
AND `products`.`sub_category` = 1 
AND `products_attributes`.`attribute_id` IN (3, 4, 5) 
GROUP BY `products`.`id`
```

Comment: *I need to get the products with the all attributes only.* `IN` is equivalent to an `OR` statement, not `AND`.